# I am having a problem in select box, where it can select multiple options, the selected option has a few objects in a sub select box

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.0

Firstly, I have a select box where i have to select multiple options. On selecting them, the code just considers the first option selected, and ignores the rest of the other options. Making me not able to save the other options.

**Views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
    user_site = UserSite.objects.get(user_id = request.POST["user_id"])
    user_site.site_id = request.POST['site']
    user_site.save()
    user_site.user.profile.roles = request.POST['role']
    user_site.user.profile.company_id = request.POST['company']
    user_site.user.profile.save()
```

[Only the option of 'Tamrind Valley' is selected, and 'Green Wood High'' is just ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWiqP.png)

**html**

```
<select class="form-control select2 edit-company-select" multiple="multiple" name="company" style="width: 100%;" required >
                        <option></option>
                        {% for company in companies %}
                        <option value="{{ company.id }}"{{company.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
```

Comment: When you have multiple selections, the correct way to fetch them is `request.POST.getlist('role')`. And if your relationship is m2m you can't just assign it with `profile.roles = ...`, you need to either use `add()` or `set()`, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: note: assigning database fields to posted values without any validation/cleaning is very very dangerous. You should not use `request.POST` values and just save them to database like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can store multiple choice using post get list
in example:

```
for i in request.POST.getlist('company'):
    company = Company.objects.create(name = i)
```